How to store and get JSON files from Unity (C#) on a local http server from a raspberry pi
we are using an apache2 http server and we would like to send data from an app and store it on the server. In the future we also would like to send some sort of activation through the server, so that the raspberry could interpret it and run a script which controls servos. The problem is we can't figure out how we can POST and GET Json files. This is the script we're using for the POST which we found on this website:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Text;

public class SerializeDict : MonoBehaviour
{
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void DictToJSON()
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(addPil.DictPilnames, Formatting.Indented);
         StartCoroutine(postRequest("http://raspberrypi.local/", json));
    }
     IEnumerator postRequest(string url, string json)
 {
     var uwr = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST"); 
     byte[] jsonToSend = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(json);
     uwr.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(jsonToSend);
     uwr.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
     uwr.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

     //Send the request then wait here until it returns
     yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

     if (uwr.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || uwr.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
     {
         Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
     }
 }
}

For the GET we're using something similar.
When we POST a JSON file and then try to GET it. The error shows a html script. We understand that the script is the html script for the URL page, but we don't know how we could GET the JSON file. We logged on to PuTTy and went to /var/www/html but there was only the html file located. The JSON files were never to be found. If anybody could help us with this or point us in the right direction we would greatly appreciate you!

When we POST a JSON file and then try to GET it. The error shows a html script. .. what do you mean POST and then try to GET ? I only see one single request which is a POST .. we don't know of course how exactly your server and API looks like .. your POST request should work if your server expects a raw JSON request body

The JSON files were never to be found .. show us your server code! The Unity code is just the POST request .. we have no clue what your server does with the information it receives ...
